# Getting MySQL cell data to an label in C#

Tags: c#, mysql

Good Day,

I'm currently trying around with the c# MySQL connector. The concept: I have a Table "**News**" with 1 Columm "**CurrentNews**" and 1 Row "**The News**".

(Picture of the Table, can't post it here for my low Rep)

[image]

So my wish would be to show "**Test News**" in my Label "**lblNews**" (In c#). I know how to show all the content of the Table in a DataGridView, but I don't need that for that thing. (Also I can't really use the knowledge of that for a Label, atleast at the moment (just started))

Thanks in advance for any possible help, it shouldn't be that hard. *I hope*

Comment: How are you fetching data from your database?  Are you following a tutorial or some examples of some kind?  (If not, I highly recommend starting with that.)  The MySQL ADO.NET objects are very similar to the normal ADO.NET objects and are generally used the same way.  So there are a *lot* of examples you can follow for how to query a database for data.

Comment: Well I'm trying it myself, I don't follow any Tutorial. Could you suggest me one I could use?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, do you wanna set the grid column the same as the field name in the table ?

Comment: Here is a full tutorial on MySQL with ADO.NET in C#: http://www.functionx.com/mysqlnet/csharp/Lesson01.htm Somewhat dated, but the beauty of plain old ADO.NET is that it hasn't had to change much in a decade. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already know how to get your data into DataGridView, then it should be simple:

```
command.CommandText = "SELECT CurrentNews FROM News";
string txtNews = Convert.ToString(command.ExecuteScalar());
lblNews.Text = txtNews;
```

You might want to replace *command* with your command variable name.